# Slow rm -rf on linux machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu

When executing `rm -rf /some/folder/*` on a directory with many files, server performance significantly goes down. Drive is Premium SSD.

Tried different ways of deleting files: `find --delete`, `rsync` (described [here](https://www.kinamo.be/en/support/faq/efficiently-remove-a-zillion-files-on-linux-servers)). Did not help.

It is an Azure issue from my experience.

By "slow" I mean 116000 files in 2 minutes 30 seconds. Locally it takes 1 second. Other server providers also 1-3 seconds.

Is there a way to delete many files fast without an impact on the performance of the server in general?

Comment: What filesystem?

Comment: Also what does this means => `It is an Azure issue` ? What is the environment

Comment: It doesn't sound too far fetched if it's a networked filesystem. A bit slow maybe, but 116000 individual `unlink()` calls could be that slow.

Comment: Good point, @Kusalananda. 1000 network unlink calls per second suddenly doesn't seem that unreasonable does it

Comment: This is normal, if the files are in one directory and the filesystem is ext[234]. Back in its days, reiserfs *really* beat the crap out of every other fs in this scenario, being something like 100 times faster. I was routinely designing my major data processing scripts to take an advantage of it and filesystem with tens of thousand of small files as a quicker alternative to a database. Unfortunately, reiserfs is almost a thing of the past...

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to delete many files fast without an impact on the performance of the server in general

You can cheat. Unfortunately it doesn't solve the issue and only pushes it out of the way. On the other hand it may be a useful workaround.

Instead of

```
rm -rf /some/folder/*
```

Use

```
items=(/some/folder/*)                      # List of items to delete
prefix=".DELETE_ME.$$"

for item in "${items[@]}"
do
    x="$${item%/*}/.$prefix.${item##*/}"    # New temporary path for item to delete
    mv -f "$item" "$x" || rm -rf "$item"    # Rename or delete
done

for item in "${items[@]}"
do
    x="$${item%/*}/.$prefix.${item##*/}"
    rm -rf "$x"                             # Delete whatever is left
done >/dev/null 2>&1 &                      # Run sequentially in background
```

You can encapsulate that in a script (parse arguments with `for item in "$@"`) or even as a shell function.

I've used two loops instead of the potentially more obvious "rename and delete in background" so that you don't destroy server performance with multiple deletes in parallel. It won't stop the impact there but it can help with the apparent speed of deletion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you may be having is that you are trying to delete 116000 files in one directory.
Deleting n files in a directory takes order n squared time.  And it can get remarkably slow.
Even `ls -l` and `find` will get bogged down.
Note that a straight `/bin/ls` will still be fairly fast, as it doesn't have to access each file.

The secret is not to get that many files in a directory to begin with.
Instead, make multiple directory levels.

Failing that, you just have to let it take time to delete.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `-exec rm -rf {} \;`:

```
find /some/dir/ -type f -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

This command will delete all your files in directory `/some/dir`

Comment: If it's `-type f` it will skip directories. Since it's skipping directories you can shorten `rm -rf {}` to `rm -f {}` because there's no recursion. And now since you're doing that you can avoid the `-exec` entirely and use `-delete`. So `find /some/dir/ -type f -delete`